# dsumutil could not find object file symbol for symbol

Tags: c++, macos, ld, debug-symbols

I merge two object file to one with command:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 13.0.0 14.0 -O3 -r first.o second.o -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -o world.o
```

Next create executable file with merged object

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch arm64 -platform_version macos 13.0.0 14.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -O3 -o executable -L/usr/local/lib main.o world.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

If i strip debug information from result executable it work fine

```
dsymutil -o executable.dSYM executable
```

but if I remove first.o second.o before run dsymutil, it generate warnings

```
first.o unable to open object file: No such file or directory
```

and

```
could not find object file symbol for symbol
```

It begins after using XCode 15 and only iOS/macOS arm64 architecture.

Any ideas how fix or suppress this dsumutil warning? I merge very large files and it produce more 10000 warnings on build.
Similar questions on trackers
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727241
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple/issues/2514
but there is no answers